# sequelize returning undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with Express js and it's linked to the postgresql database.

I am trying to return all vendors in the table vendors (columns: vendor, category and id). I am using the following findall() function to achieve this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  models.vendors.findAll({attributes: ['vendor','category','id']}).then(function(vendors) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Budget',
      vendors: vendors
    });
    console.log(vendors[0])
  });
});
```

The output of the console.log is the following

```
vendors {
   dataValues:
   { vendor: 'FIRSTVENDOR',
     category: null,
     id: 1},
....
```

The following function returns undefined instead of the expected 'FIRSTVENDOR'.

```
console.log(vendors[0].vendor)
```

However the following function works.

```
console.log(vendors[0].id)
```

I imagine I need to somehow declare the variable types?

To create the database I executed the following:

```
CREATE TABLE vendors(id serial, vendor text primary key, category text default NULL, total float8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in the model object. I replaced

```
  const vendors = sequelize.define('vendors', {
    vendors: DataTypes.STRING
   }, {});
```

with

```
  const vendors = sequelize.define('vendors', {
    vendor: DataTypes.STRING,
    category: Datatypes.STRING
   }, {});
```